# How to "intersperse" two lists by a key value?

Tags: elixir

I have two lists of maps and I want to form a list that would contain values from both lists basing on some common values.

```
list1 = [
  %{email: "email1", name: "name1"},
  %{email: "email2", name: "name2"}
]

list2 = [
  %{"email" => "email3", "name" => "new name3"},
  %{"email" => "email2", "name" => "new name2"}
]
```

The lists may be different size, one of them may even be empty.

The desired output would be:

```
[
  {%{email: "email1", name: "name1"}, nil},
  {%{email: "email2", name: "name2"},
   %{"email" => "email2", "name" => "new name2"}},
  {nil, %{"email" => "email3", "name" => "new name3"}}
]
```

Here is an implementation I came up with:

```
  # to produce the output above, call it with
  # list_intersperse(list1, list2, :email, "email")
  def list_intersperse(list1, list2, key1, key2) do
    map2 = Enum.map(list2, fn elem -> {elem[key2], elem} end) |> Map.new()

    result =
      Enum.map(list1, fn elem ->
        common_value = Map.get(elem, key1)
        {elem, map2[common_value]}
      end)

    keys1 = Enum.map(list1, fn elem -> Map.get(elem, key1) end) |> MapSet.new()

    result ++
      (list2
       |> Enum.reject(&MapSet.member?(keys1, &1[key2]))
       |> Enum.map(&{nil, &1}))
  end
```

The implementation feels sub-optimal to me and it's hard to read. Am I missing something, could it be done in a more concise and more readable way?

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you want, and should update the example to match your real data. You said "one of them may even be empty" but didn't specify which one. If it's the left, the last solution you mentioned would return no items. I don't think this can be answered in its current form - there's no use people guessing what your data is and then you retrospectively adding conditions when the answers don't work on the data you didn't provide...

Comment: Yep. I dig deeper and I found it's even more complex that it's on "update". I'll remove the update and will accept the answer, because the solution is really nice for the data I originally provided.

Comment: I've posted my own answer with an updated dataset that incluses some real-life "complications" I see in the data I have: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66853823/1173020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```elixir
def pair(list1, list2) do
  map1 = Map.new(list1, fn item -> {item.email, item} end)
  map2 = Map.new(list2, fn item -> {item["email"], item} end)

  all_emails = MapSet.new(Map.keys(map1) ++ Map.keys(map2))
  for email <- all_emails, do: {map1[email], map2[email]}
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.pair(list1, list2)
[
  {%{email: "email1", name: "name1"}, nil},
  {%{email: "email2", name: "name2"},
   %{"email" => "email2", "name" => "new name2"}},
  {nil, %{"email" => "email3", "name" => "new name3"}}
]
```

Comment: I tried this on my example, works well! But then I tried this on real data and found that it's possible to have multiple empty strings or `nil` in email in both lists. In this case, search by `nil` or empty strings won't work.
Thanks and +1 for the answer, but I can't really use it :-(

Comment: What you're asking for seems to be impossible. You want to pair up two lists with potentially no common data. Then how are you supposed to form the pairs?

Comment: You are right. I'm accepting the answer, because I found some even more complex cases and I don't really want to dig that deep.

Comment: I dig deeper and built another function that does what I wanted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66853823/1173020

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works perfectly for the data set I've posted in the question, but it turned out that my data set has some duplicated data on both sides.

For example:

```
list1 = [
  %{email: nil, name: "nil1"},
  %{email: nil, name: "nil2"},
  %{email: "email1", name: "name1"},
  %{email: "email2", name: "name2"}
]

list2 = [
  %{"email" => "email3", "name" => "new name3"},
  %{"email" => "email2", "name" => "new name2"},
  %{"email" => "email2", "name" => "new name2"}
]
```

In the first list there are two items with duplicated keys and both of them `nil`, and in the second list there are two keys with the same values equals to `email2`.

I need to keep all these values in the resulting data set, so mapping by key won't work.

What I ended up doing is using `List.myers_difference` function and transforming its results into the list I want to see:

```
def list_intersperse(list1, list2, key1, key2) do
  list1 = Enum.sort_by(list1, &Map.get(&1, key1))
  list2 = Enum.sort_by(list2, &Map.get(&1, key2))

  List.myers_difference(list1, list2, fn elem1, elem2 ->
    if Map.get(elem1, key1) == Map.get(elem2, key2), do: {elem1, elem2}
  end)
  |> Enum.map(&myers_to_intersperse/1)
  |> List.flatten()
end

defp myers_to_intersperse({:del, list}), do: Enum.map(list, &{&1, nil})
defp myers_to_intersperse({:ins, list}), do: Enum.map(list, &{nil, &1})
defp myers_to_intersperse({:diff, tuple}), do: tuple
```

The code above gives the result I wanted:

```
[
  {%{email: nil, name: "nil1"}, nil},
  {%{email: nil, name: "nil2"}, nil},
  {%{email: "email1", name: "name1"}, nil},
  {%{email: "email2", name: "name2"}, %{"email" => "email2", "name" => "new name2"}},
  {nil, %{"email" => "email2", "name" => "new name2"}},
  {nil, %{"email" => "email3", "name" => "new name3"}}
]
```